# Property attribute in class extension does not match the primary class

Tags: ios, objective-c, warnings, clang, compiler-warnings

I'm implementing the NSFilePresenter protocol:

```
@protocol NSFilePresenter <NSObject>
@required

@property (readonly, copy) NSURL *presentedItemURL;
@property (readonly, retain) NSOperationQueue *presentedItemOperationQueue;

@end
```

Of course I would like to access `presentedItemURL` and `presentedItemOperationQueue` writing internally too.

So I declared my private interface like this:

```
@interface MyClass () <NSFilePresenter>

@property (copy) NSURL *presentedItemURL;
@property (retain) NSOperationQueue *presentedItemOperationQueue;

@end
```

But `presentedItemURL` will return a warning:

```
'copy' attribute on property 'presentedItemURL' does not match the property inherited from 'NSFilePresenter'
```

We might discuss if this warning makes sense here at all. But all I want to achieve is to get rid of the warning without writing my own setter, using KV-coding or any other trick.
Oddly enough the compiler is fine with `presentedItemOperationQueue`.

Even using this doesn't solve the problem

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wall"
@property (copy) NSURL *presentedItemURL;
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Comment: This is a clang bug. If you are looking into https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/Sema/SemaObjCProperty.cpp#L1301 `Sema::DiagnosePropertyMismatch` there is a check are a list of checks. The first one checks of if the inherited property is readwrite and the other one is not. This will generate a warning.
The second check is if both properties are `copy`. If one is and the other is not it will generate the warning described above. But clang is unable to determine the attributes your property which will lead to the warning. Also there is not way to suppress this warning.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using the default specifiers (and not stating any). For your example:

```
@interface MyClass () <NSFilePresenter>

@property NSURL *presentedItemURL;
@property NSOperationQueue *presentedItemOperationQueue;

@end
```

In modern Objective-C that means `atomic` and `strong` references.